# Which Windows edition to use as a build server for Windows Phone 8 projects?

Tags: windows-phone-8, build-server, windows-server-2012

We plan to create virtual machine to serve as a build server for our Windows Phone 8 projects. According to the official requirements the WP8 SDK runs only on Windows 8. The question is **is it possible to install the VS2012 and WP8 SDK also on Windows Server 2012**, or should we just use the supported Windows 8?
Note we use Hyper-V for hosting virtual machines and also we don't need the WP8 emulator on that build server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a possible alternative (as I haven't tested your issue of building on WS 2012), why don't you use TFS online? It allows for 5 free projects (privately hosted in the cloud). See more here: http://tfs.visualstudio.com/

More on your issue:
I have tried running the WP8 SDK on Windows 7 without any luck (but it's not supported so I understand). Also, I have tried running the WP8 SDK from a Windows 8 Virtual Machine, but the emulator did not run as Hyper-V can't run on Hyper-V without pursuing this option: http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Windows_Phone_8_SDK_on_a_Virtual_Machine_with_Working_Emulator

Hope this helps in some way, shape, or form.

Answer (score 0):

On my workstation are installed VS2012, WP8 SDK. All works fine.